# MSE For a Single Calculation (intel processor errors)

Tags: statistics, mean-square-error

This is the question, from a practice final for a stat course:

> The Intel Pentium Processor chip has been discovered to make small
>   errors  occasionally; that is, errors of +1 or –1 (in $10^{-4}$ units)
>   in a small fraction of its calculations.  Suppose that these occur in
>   a single calculation with probability 0.0005 each, and that  otherwise
>   the results are correct. Suppose further that positive and negative
>   errors are  equally frequent. An Intel engineer discovers a partial
>   “fix” that would eliminate the  chance of negative errors by making
>   all errors positive (so the chance of a positive error  would become
>   0.001). Which chip would have smaller Mean Squared Error for a single  calculation, old or new?

I'm having trouble starting (with a start, I think I could figure it out). I know that $MSE = E[(\theta+\hat\theta)^2]$, so I tried to say that for part I the expected error is $.0005(-.0001)+.0005(.0001)=0$ and for part II the expected error would be $.001(.0001)=.0000001$ so the second would have a higher MSE, but that doesn't seem intuitively correct. I may be messing up something obvious -- way to long in the library today.

Comment: Oh man, Intel's never going to live that one down... (The real bug was much less frequent than stated here, though).

Comment: @ Henning Makholm:  you mean there's a true story behind this?  Love to hear it!  Got a link?